# Display html if one of more variables are not empty

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I want to echo some html if a variable isn't empy, for this I know I can do the following:

```
if (!empty($test)) {
?>
    <p>Some nice html can go here</p> 
<?php
} 
else 
{ 
echo "It's empty...";
}
```

How can I do this for several variables? So if one of the variables are not empty then echo the html? Would this do it?

```
if (!empty($test || $image || $anothervar)) {
?>
    <p>Some nice html can go here</p> 
<?php
} 
else 
{ 
echo "It's empty...";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
if (!empty($test) || !empty($image) || !empty($anothervar)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check every variable:

```
!empty($test) || !empty($image) || !empty($anothervar)
```

Answer (score 1):

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function does not take multiple arguments.

So, you need to user `empty` separately for each variable.

The final code should be:

```
if (!empty($test)  || !empty($image) || !empty($anothervar)) {
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, the OP’s code passes _the only one_ argument to `empty`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check all the three variables.

Also, I advise you to embed your php into your html to have a better readable document, like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($test) || !empty($image) || !empty($anothervar)): ?>
    <p>Some nice html can go here</p> 
<?php else: ?>
    It's empty...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution:

```
if(empty($test) and empty($image) and empty($anothervar)) {
   echo "It's completely empty...";
} else {
?>
    <p>Some nice html can go here</p> 
<?php
}
```

Or if you have a lot of variables to check:

```
$check = array("test","image","anothervar");
$empty = true;
foreach($check as $var) {
   if(! empty($$var)) {
      $empty = false;
   }
}
if($empty) {
   echo "It's completely empty...";
} else {
?>
    <p>Some nice html can go here</p> 
<?php
}
```